# Subtraction in same table in same row with where condition #SQL

Tags: sql

Using a SQL query to subtract in same table:

Table1

```
grade   record  total_amount
------------------------------
DSP     receipt     17258
DSP     sales       16313
OPC43   receipt     95442
OPC43   sales       92856
OPC53   receipt    371752
OPC53   sales      368985
PPC     receipt    156023
PPC     sales      152803
vajram  receipt     36100
vajram  sales       36100
```

Answer needed

```
 945    DSP
2586    OPC43
2767    OPC53
3220    PPC
   0    vajram
```

Comment: please format this so it is readable, it's impossible to tell where rows and columns begin and end

Answer (score 0):

Is there ever only two entries per grade? Always just a `receipt` and `sales`? If that's the case, then something like the following would do the trick

```
SELECT receipt.total_amount - sales.total_amount, grade 
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE record = 'receipt') receipt
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE record = 'sales') sales
       ON receipt.grade = sales.grade
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like that:

```
select grade, sum(case when record = 'receipt' then total_amount else 0-total_amount end)
from table
group by grade
```